# How does the JAVA reflection API know which method to pass the parameters to?

Tags: java

I have 4 different methods, where only one requires a parameter:

```
foo1 (){}
foo2 (){}
foo3 (String data) {}
foo4 (){}
```

I am invoking these methods using the Java Reflection API. My code looks like this at the moment:

```
            Mymethod method = new ActionKeyWords();

            Method [] methods = method.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();

            for (Method s : methods) {

                    if (s.getName().contains("foo3")) {

                        System.out.println("Executing method: " + s.getName());
                        s.invoke(s.getName(),"data");


                    else
                        System.out.println("Executing method: " + s.getName());
                        s.invoke(s.getName());

                }

            }
```

You can see that I am making a control to see if the methods name is foo3 before invoking the method. That is because that method is the only method I want to pass a  parameter too. If I remove the if statement I get a `"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments".`

How else would the API know which function I want to pass a parameter to? At the moment only foo3 requires a parameter, but what if foo98 requires it as well.

The reason why I chose the reflection API was to get rid of the endless if statements in my code.

Is this the only solution? Is there a smarter way to solve this?

Comment: reflection api wouldn't know. error comes at runtime. reflection isn't the solution for getting rid of if-else. you need to revisit your design

Comment: Typically reflection operations are expensive, you should only use reflection sparingly and as a last-resort. If you gave a better background of the problem you are attempting to solve, it's likely a better solution could be proposed.

Comment: `How does the JAVA reflection API know which method to pass the parameters to?` java reflection api does not know which method to pass parameters to. You are indicating method name and arguments, you know it

Answer (score 2):

In order to check what parameters that are part of the signature of a `Method`, use `Method#getParameterTypes`.

Answer (score 0):

The Reflection API isn't at fault here, because it expects you to do the filtering.

You shouldn't use Reflection like this to get rid of a long list of 'if statements'. Reflection calls are multiple times more expensive than almost anything thing else you could do.

You might want to try a 'switch' statement instead of a series of if/else (depending on what exactly your impl. is)

---

as sidgate and Kayaman said, using reflection will cause a lot of problems for you when it comes to your design of your project.

The reason being is that you can't use good design principles, nor can you make use of IDE features/tools that will analyze your code and do analysis.

If you have a class with a method a long list of if/else statements to decide which constructor/method to call, then perhaps you should use a ['construction pattern'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern) such as the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or perhaps even the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) (but the decision on which to use will depend on your specific Implementation/needs)

Comment: It's not the performance that's the problem with reflection, it's the havoc it wreaks on the design.

Comment: Yes, that is true, I just gave 'one' reason why its a bad idea. Will edit to add this.